# Collecting all ethenities and instances used in a project for mapping in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

For security review purposes I would like to export a list of every entity, user (human and non-human) and instance used within a single project. So I could make a mapping/drawing of how the project data flow actually runs and what is used in it, which is absolute and what is legacy.

Is there a function that does this in Google Cloud or a third party method created with the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view what roles the users are granted for your project by getting the project IAM policy, using the Cloud Console, the **[gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#getting-policy)** command-line tool, or the `getIamPolicy()` [method](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/organizations/getIamPolicy).

The following example shows the get-iam-policy command for projects:

`gcloud projects get-iam-policy project-id`

The command outputs the policy, which will be similar to the following:

```
bindings:
- members:
  - user:testuser1@gcp-test.com
  role: roles/editor
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-123456789@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/container.serviceAgent
- members:
  - user:testuser2@gcp-test.com
 role: roles/owner
etag": "BwU1aRxXk30="
```

Also,  you can list all instances  you have in your project,  using the Cloud Console  `gcloud compute instances list` [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/list) or the `instances.list()` [method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list).

To list all instances in a project in table form, run:
`gcloud compute instances list`

You will get something like :

```
NAME        ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP   STATUS
instance-1  us-central1-a  n1-standard-1               10.128.0.44  31.71.191.51  RUNNING
```

It is worth mentioning that you can filter and format the output of these commands,  please check the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/filtering-and-formatting-fun-with) for more details.

As an example I've executed the following command that lists my instances in my project:

```
gcloud compute instances list --format="table[box,title='My Instances List'](creationTimestamp,description,name,id,zone,machineType,networkInterfaces.accessConfigs.natIP,status)"
```

And I get the following output:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                               My Instances List                                                               │
├───────────────────────────────┬─────────────┬────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────────┬───────────────┬────────────────────┬─────────┤
│       CREATION_TIMESTAMP      │ DESCRIPTION │    NAME    │          ID         │      ZONE     │  MACHINE_TYPE │       NAT_IP       │  STATUS │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────┼────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────┤
│ 2020-08-13T08:08:41.600-07:00 │             │ instance-1 │ 4795755120481234567 │ us-central1-b │ n1-standard-1 │ [['31.71.191.51']] │ RUNNING │
└───────────────────────────────┴─────────────┴────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────┘
```

Additionally,  you might  use OS inventory management to collect operating system and package information that is stored as guest attributes on the Compute Engine metadata.  I have found the following [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/view-os-details#enable-guest-attributes) to enable guest attributes and OS inventory management

I hope you find  this information useful.

Comment: Thanks this was actually what I needed. :)

Comment: I'm happy to help :)